# Keep ProtoBuf message in Room

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, android-room

I want to store some proto message in room database. I've declared:

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class ProtoConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromArray(array: ByteArray): MyProto.MyMessage {
        return MyProto.MyMessage.parseFrom(array)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toArray(msg: MyProto.MyMessage): ByteArray {
        return msg.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

my event (simplified)

```
@Entity
data class SomeEvent(
    ...
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_REQUEST) val msg: MyProto.MyMessage,
    ...
)
```

I'm getting errors and can't build project:

for converter class

```
 Invalid return type for a type converter.
    public final error.NonExistentClass fromArray(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

for entity

```
Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
    private final error.NonExistentClass msg = null;
```

looks like `error.NonExistentClass` is thrown in a place of `MyProto.MyMessage`, probably during (debug) building at first kapt is resolving annotations and after that my proto is (re-)built, too late...

how can I fix that using converters instead of defining `ByteArray` instead of proto in entity?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could have something like:-

```
@Entity
data class SomeEvent(
    ...
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_REQUEST) val msg: ByteArray = mp_msg.toByteArray
    ...
) {
    constructor(mpmsg: MyProto.MyMessage) : this(msg = mpmsg.toByteArray())

    fun getAsMyProto_dot_Message(): MyProto.Message {
        return MyProto.MyMessage.parseFrom(msg)
    }
}
```

- with no need for Type Converters

I'm not 100% sure that Room will like it, but using a substitute for the MyProto.Message :-

```
data class MyTest(
    val xxx: ByteArray
) {
    companion object {
        fun toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            return byteArrayOf(100)
        }
        fun fromByteArray(byteArray: ByteArray): MyTest {
            return MyTest(byteArray)
        }
    }
}
```

And then:-

```
@Entity
data class SomeEvent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    var msg: ByteArray = MyTest.toByteArray()
) {
    constructor(myTest: MyTest) : this(msg = MyTest.toByteArray())
    fun getMsgAsMyTest(): MyTest {
        return MyTest.fromByteArray(msg)
    }
}
```

And using

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class,SomeEvent::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
```

- Item included because I hijacked a project used for another question.

Then using :-

```
    val se1 = SomeEvent(MyTest(byteArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
    val se2 = SomeEvent(msg = byteArrayOf(5,4,3,2,1))
    val se3 = SomeEvent(msg = byteArrayOf(10,11,12,13,14))

    val mt1  = se1.getMsgAsMyTest()
    val mt2 = se2.getMsgAsMyTest()
    val mt3 = se3.getMsgAsMyTest()
```

With a breakpoint on the next line of code then:

- a) it compiles (so one step further)
- b) it runs to the breakpoint
- c) appears to do what is needed as per the following:

[image]

Adding the following in the @Dao annotated interface:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(someEvent: SomeEvent): Long
@Query("SELECT * FROM someEvent")
fun getAllSomeEvents(): List<SomeEvent>
```

And then adding the following code (after the above code) to be run (on the main thread for brevity and convenience):

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDao()
    dao.insert(SomeEvent(MyTest( byteArrayOf(99,99,99,99,99))))
    dao.insert(SomeEvent(id = 1234, msg = byteArrayOf(33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33)))
    val allSomeEvents = dao.getAllSomeEvents()
```

And then using App Inspection:

[image]

Both rows have been inserted, but the first only has a single byte (due to the MyTest.toByteArray function just setting the byteArray to 100 (hex 64) my bad)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've ended up with similar aproach, but both our solutions are involving additional extra code for ommiting problem, not fixing sadly...